# Remove content from a view

Tags: views

I have a Master view & numerous child views for the same content type. The Master View has all nodes from the content type. The content gets copied to the child view from the master view basis of specific requirements by the user. I want to have the functionality to remove specific content from the child views. I do not want to delete it as the content would be reused for others from the Master View.

Is there any module to achieve this?

I am not developer.

Comment: You can, it depends on what you want exactly. You can add filters on the right side when you edit a view for static filtering or for exposed one. Or you can add contextual filters (under the advanced) for dynamic filtering (i.e. pass arguments between pages, and/or get current user right and filter by that way.) Also, don't forget to set Overwrite this page only when you add something filter, or it will add to all views/blocks/etc.

Comment: Thank you for the tip golddragon007. The exposed filters are in the Master View which are used to bring the result down & copied across to the Child Views. Once in the Child View, the user, depending on their requirements, remove irrelevant nodes from here. I want to ensure that when the nodes are deleted from the Child View it does not get deleted from the Master View. How can I go about to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Well, if you delete a content, it will be deleted from the system. So mostly you need to flag a content by the user, because the user is not interested in it. In this case the content will be still exist. For this you can use the flag (https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module, than you need to set a filter for the content where the user didn't set it for 'delete' state.

Comment: Thank you golddragon007. Let me try that. It seems to be a far more sensible advice than my Google search results. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on a field or a setting. At the very top, you need to use the **For** "override" option. (select `This [view type] override`) so it only affects your current view.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the dramatic edit, but IMO the answer needs to be more noob friendly.

Comment: Thanks @NoSssweat i have seen the edit part. Now its really look good and clear to understand.